# Is Angular setting a "checked" property in the DOM invisible to dev tools?

Tags: html, css, angular, dom

In the following screenshot of the DOM from Chrome's dev tools, I have a radio input with a following label. A CSS style is applied to the label only when the previous sibling input is `:checked`.

The value of the radio button input is determined by an Angular `[(ngModel)]` property. You can see here the model property matches the value property for this input, so I assume that's how it's determined as `checked`, because otherwise no property for it seems to exist in the DOM.

How is the CSS determining it should be applied here without the explicit `checked` property? Is something not being reflected in the dev tools?

[image: Browser tool screenshot of markup/styles on Input/Label element]

Comment: This isn't related to Angular. The `<input checked>` property will only show in the DOM in your Dev Tools if it was explicitly written in the HTML (as a default attribute on that element). It won't show up when you toggle an input.

Comment: @JonUleis Thanks, you're right. I'm having issues with cases where value and model match and `checked` isn't even set invisibly though, so I may need to ask another question to debug I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses different things in most cases. A checked input will get the class `ng-not-empty`, when not checked it will be the `ng-emtpy` class.

However, the checked property will only be visible if set in the HTML explicitly. But CSS will still work though.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see `ng-empty` in this case, I assume it's determined by model matching value. But I see what you mean about checked not being visible explicitly. How do I debug if model and value match but checked is not set?

Comment: Try asking antoher question related to the model matching. I'm honestly not a great Angular expert :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll do that, shame I wasted this on the easy issue.